# Chisel invert Vec[Bool] one-liner

Tags: chisel

Is there a one-liner that takes a Vec[Bool] and creates an inverted version of it?

Here is an example of taking 37 bits, inverting them, then doing an OR reduction across all of them. Is there a one-liner that can replace the assignment of inv_a?

```
class MyModule extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val a = Input(Vec(37, Bool()))
    val b = Output(Bool())
  })

  val inv_a = Wire(Vec(37, Bool()))
  for (i <- 0 until 37) {
    inv_a(i) := ~io.a(i)
  }

  io.b := inv_a.reduce((a, b) => (a | b))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want.

```
val inv_a = (~ io.a.asUInt).asBools()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could `map` on the input `Vec` to invert each element:

```scala
val inv_a = io.a.map(!_)
```

Example in a Scastie (using Chisel v3.4.4): https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bcQIihPMThelC9h4jDfyxQ

Note that the type of `inv_a` is a `Seq[Bool]` which you can still do your `reduce` on, but if you need a `Vec[Bool]` back you'll need to wrap the result in `VecInit(...)`:

```scala
val inv_a: Vec[Bool] = VecInit(io.a.map(!_))
```